# How to show a custom 404 page in ASP.NET without redirect?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

When a request is 404 in ASP.NET on IIS 7 i want a custom error page to be displayed. The URL in the address bar should not change, so no redirect. How can i do this?

Comment: You have a lot of tags - is this webforms or MVC?

Answer (score 8):

As a general ASP.NET solution, in the customErrors section in the web.config, add the redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" attribute.

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="/404.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

Note: this internally uses a Server.Transfer() so the redirect must be an actual file on the webserver. It can't be an MVC route.

Comment: NB This was added in 3.5 SP1.

Comment: I have a web page that throws InvalidOperationException which results in a 500 error being returned.  However, when I added the above configuration snippet, the error page is displayed, but the HTTP status code is changed to 200. Using ASP.NET 4.0 and 4.5.

Comment: Yeah the work around is to manually set the Response.StatusCode in the overridden Render method in 404.aspx.cs. There's probably a better solution but this seems to work.

Comment: so why do you redirect to an ASPX page if it has to be a static file  :-)

Comment: It doesn't. The file just has to exist on the file system. I suppose you could use a HTML file if you want. In my case, the ASPX page renders dynamic content in the error page.

Answer (score 3):

I use an http module to handle this. It works for other types of errors, not just 404s, and allows you to continue using the custom errors web.config section to configure which page is displayed.

```
public class CustomErrorsTransferModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.Error += Application_Error;
    }

    public void Dispose()  {  }

    private void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var error = Server.GetLastError();
        var httpException = error as HttpException;
        if (httpException == null)
            return;

        var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/customErrors") as CustomErrorsSection;
        if (section == null)
            return;

        if (!AreCustomErrorsEnabledForCurrentRequest(section))
            return;

        var statusCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
        var customError = section.Errors[statusCode.ToString()];

        Response.Clear();
        Response.StatusCode = statusCode;

        if (customError != null)
            Server.Transfer(customError.Redirect);
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(section.DefaultRedirect))
            Server.Transfer(section.DefaultRedirect);
    }

    private bool AreCustomErrorsEnabledForCurrentRequest(CustomErrorsSection section)
    {
        return section.Mode == CustomErrorsMode.On ||
               (section.Mode == CustomErrorsMode.RemoteOnly && !Context.Request.IsLocal);
    }

    private HttpResponse Response
    {
        get { return Context.Response; }
    }

    private HttpServerUtility Server
    {
        get { return Context.Server; }
    }

    private HttpContext Context
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current; }
    }
}
```

enable in your web.config in the same way as any other module

```
<httpModules>
     ...
     <add name="CustomErrorsTransferModule" type="WebSite.CustomErrorsTransferModule, WebSite" />
     ...
</httpModules>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Server.Transfer("404error.aspx")
```